# Django - use reverse url mapping in settings

Tags: python, django, url, dry

A few of the options in the django settings file are urls, for example `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.   Is it possible to avoid hardcoding these urls, and instead use reverse url mapping?    At the moment this is really the only place where I find myself writing the same urls in multiple places.

Comment: I doubt it, since `settings.py` is loaded before the URL module. Interested to find out though. Great question.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

## Django 1.5 and later

As of Django 1.5, `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` accept named URL patterns. That means you don't need to hardcode any urls in your settings.

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'  # name of url pattern
```

For Django 1.5 - 1.9, you can also use the view function name, but this is not recommended because it is deprecated in Django 1.8 and won't work in Django 1.10+.

```
LOGIN_URL = 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' # path to view function
```

## Django 1.4

For Django 1.4, you can could use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)

```
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
```

## Django 1.3 and earlier

This is the original answer, which worked before `reverse_lazy` was added to Django

In urls.py, import settings:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Then add the url pattern

```
urlpatterns=('',
    ...
    url('^%s$' %settings.LOGIN_URL[1:], 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', 
        name="login")
    ...
)
```

Note that you need to slice `LOGIN_URL` to remove the leading forward slash.

In the shell:

```
>>>from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>>reverse('login')
'/accounts/login/'
```

Comment: Ah, good solution, I didn't consider going from settings -> urls, only the other way around. +1

Comment: And can you avoid hard-coding the django root, so that /accounts/login resolves to /root/accounts/login if your django app is deployed on example.com/root rather than example.com/ ?

Comment: @gozzilli - since Django 1.4, I would use `reverse_lazy` instead of importing `settings.LOGIN_URL` into the urls. I've updated the answer.

Comment: For me with Django 2.1 the LOGIN_URL_REDIRECT with name of url pattern ist not working. It gives me a 404 error and {'path':'name_of_url'}. Has there something changed? In the documentation I can't finde anything.

Comment: @tobit please asks new question, you haven’t provided enough information to show what the problem is. There shouldn’t be any changes in Django 2.1 that effect this.

Answer (score 14):

In django development version reverse_lazy() becomes an option:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy

Comment: It's scheduled for te 1.4 release in March 2012