# django newbie: try to reverse auth.views.login in login_required() decorator

Tags: django, django-views

I'm new to stackoverflow and to django...

Brief question (see below for "long question"), the following code in myapps/views.py failed:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
...
@login_required(login_url=reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login'))
def my_view(request):
   pass
```

The error is:

```
ViewDoesNotExist at /
tried my-view2 in module myproject.myapps.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'my-view2'
```

'my-view2' is defined in myapps/views.py after my-view (and is referenced in myproject/urls.py)

I guess there is something like chicken and egg here but I can't figure out where I'm wrong.
I try to set up LOGIN_URL in settings.py like that with the same error:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
...
LOGIN_URL=reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login')
```

Now long question (what context, why I want do that):

working with django 1.3.1 I got the following view, protected with auth.decorator:

```
@login_required
def my_view(request)
  pass
```

This decorator default redirect to /accounts/login (it works and that fine for me).

Using developpement server the whole urls are relative to localhost:/

In production server (using wsgi), the whole urls are relative to my-server:/path1/
This is due to the apache configuration that say something like:
WSGIScriptAlias /path1 /var/www/path/to/script.wsgi

And that's fine for me.

All urls defined in myproject/urls.py are automagically relative to this new path, so thanks to django, all my site is working on this new "html root".

But my protected view still redirect to my-server:/accounts/login/ instead o my-server:/path1/accounts/login

so far I make it work using settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL=/path1/accounts/login/
```

or using login_url parameter of "login_required" decorator:

```
@login_required(login_url="/path1/accounts/login/")
```

But I would like that this login view be relative to the whole site path without configuring "path1" in both apache and django/settings.py

I don't feel that using reverse in settings.py is the right thing to do
nor using it in a view decorator. But so far I don't know how to handle this...

Comment: do you really have a view defined as `my-view2`? It's not a valid python name, `-` being an operator. If you do, you should rename it to `my_view2`.

Answer (score 14):

You can't use `reverse` in the `login_required` decorator or in `settings.py`, because the URL config hasn't been loaded at the time the settings/views are imported.

In Django 1.4+, you can use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-lazy). On earlier versions of Django, you could backport `reverse_lazy`, or see my answer to the question [reverse url mapping in settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518286/django-use-reverse-url-mapping-in-settings).

In Django 1.5+, the `LOGIN_URL` setting accepts named url patterns. For example, if you name your login URL pattern 'login', then you can simply do:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: Thanks for your accurate answer! the option you gave is interesting. Knowing it's not possible in version 1.3.1 I will save some time trying to make it works!

Comment: Thank you. I ran into this issue making my own decorator and had to make sure it did not force the evaluation of `reverse_lazy(...)` too early either.

Answer (score 0):

following reverse() function, I find out another way to achieve my goal:

I'm ok with using standard urls (accounts/login, etc.)
I just want to prepend the html document root that is not "/" in my case.

from my test, this does not work in settings.py (it's too early at this step ?)

in my views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="/path1/accounts/login/")
```

become

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import get_script_prefix
@login_required(login_url=get_script_prefix() + "accounts/login/")
```

Comment: You are hardcoding the URL, this violates DRY!

Answer (score 0):

use `reverse_lazy()`

[documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) say:

It is useful for when you need to use a URL reversal before your project’s URLConf is loaded. Some common cases where this function is necessary are:

- providing a reversed URL as the url attribute of a generic class-based view.
- **providing a reversed URL to a decorator** (such as the login_url argument for the django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required() decorator).
- providing a reversed URL as a default value for a parameter in a function’s signature.